# calculus midpoint rule Find N for guaranteed error

Tags: calculus

[image]

For part a i get that its asking to use the midpoint trap and simpsons rule

I dont understand how to solve part b. Do i have to plug in the error somewhere and solve for n? or do i want the answer to be less than 10^-4? Why is it mentioning the 4th derivative of the function as a hint?

some clarification on what the question is asking and/or a push in the right direction would really help me.

Answer (score 1):

I will do it for midpoint rule and leave other for you. Denote
$$
h= \frac{2-0}{N}=\frac{2}{4} = \frac12
$$
and
$$
x_i = 0 + \frac12 (2i -1)h = \frac12(2i-1)\frac12, \quad i =1,2,3,4
$$
The sum for midpoint rule for given function is then
$$ 
M_N = h\sum_{i=1}^N \cos(x_i^3) = \frac12 (\cos(\frac1{64}) + \cos(\frac{27}{64}) + \cos(\frac{125}{64}) + \cos(\frac{343}{64}))
$$
Without derivation (via Taylor expansion) the formula to bound the midpoint rule error $E_M$ is
$$
E_M \leq \frac{h^2(2-0)}{24}\Bigg| \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\cos(x^3) \Bigg|
$$
It follows ($h=\frac{2}{N}$)
$$
E_M \leq \frac{1}{6N^2} \Bigg| \frac{d}{dx}(-\sin(x^3)3x^2) \Bigg| = \frac{1}{6N^2} \Bigg| -\cos(x^3)9x^4 - \sin(x^3)6x \Bigg|
$$
The absolute value of the second derivative reaches its maximum value $144.27$ at $x=2$ (checked by Mathematica). Your error is therefore bounded by
$$
E_M \leq \frac{24.4}{N^2} \leq 10^{-4}
$$
This translates to
$$
N^2 \geq 244000
$$
or 
$$
N \geq \sqrt{244000} = 493.97
$$ 
Consider a bit of rounding error...your $N$ should be at least $494$.

You will need the approximation of fourth derivative when calculating error of the Simpson's rule.

Comment: how did you get that h is 2/n?

Comment: You divide interval from 0 to 2 in N parts...this is your h

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ApproximatingDefIntegrals.aspx):

The error in approximating an integral by Simpson's rule is

$$\frac{1}{180n^4} \left(b-a\right)^5 \left|f^{(4)}(\xi)\right|$$

where $\xi$ is some number between $a$ and $b$.

We want to find a value of of $n$ that makes the error term (the above expression) $\leq 10^{-4}$. Do we know what $a$ and $b$ are? Do we have an upper bound on the fourth derivative of $f$?

Analogous forms hold true for the midpoint and trapezoidal rule involving lower derivatives of $f$.